# http request fails in ionic android 8+

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4

my ionic 4 HTTP request is not working fine in android 9, but in android < 9 it working perfectly. after debug the app it shows fail status in the network tab. I have added.

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
</edit-config>
```

and

```
<widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="1.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

in config.xml file and change the android:targetSdkVersion

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
```

in AndroidManifest.xml file. but these are also not useable .please help me out in this.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced this problem also, but I have a solution that is working in my case. Follow these 4 steps below.

step 1: create a directory named xml in "resources/android/" and create a new file named 
 network_security_config.xml.

step 2: add this following code in this network_security_config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

step 3: add this code following code in config.xml file under android platform like below

```
<platform name="android">

  <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" 
   target="/manifest/application" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <application 
       android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
    </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" 
    target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />

    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
```

step 4: don't use targetSdkVersion=29, it will work in 28, use below target version.

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**--------------- http:// and https:// ---------------**

In **Android 9, 10**, and above versions, they only accept **'HTTPS'** requests. **If we are debugging our debug build in an Android device(in chrome inspect) having android versions of 5,6,7,8 or lower versions than 5,** then we don't feel any issue, and also in lower versions of android accept **'HTTP'** requests. **This is because the android team had improved its security and not accepting HTTP requests, because as we know that HTTP is a non-secure request.**

*This was a major problem on which I gets stuck when I was a beginner. And this might be a common mistake (a careless mistake).*

**For solving this issue then just add an 's' in http:// requests to make it like https:// request**

***For example -- (if your API link is just like the first one shown below then change your link just like the second one)***

[1.http://web.global.com/Campus/api/login](http://web.global.com/Campus/api/login)

[2.https://web.global.com/Campus/api/login](https://web.global.com/Campus/api/login)

*I hope this solution will help u in solving the problem and have a great day buddy...*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).